# lightweight, non-framework lightbox with next/previous arrows for commercial use

Tags: javascript, lightbox

I'm looking for a lightbox script which meets all the following criteria:

1. Must be free for commercial usage
2. Must be lightweight
3. Must not require a framework
4. allows browsing of a group of photos using next/previous links
5. Must work in all major browser (including IE9 and FF4)
6. Allow captions

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472323/lightweight-non-framework-lightbox-with-next-previous-arrows-for-commercial-use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I continued to look after posting and found that the following lightbox does everything I need.

http://serennz.sakura.ne.jp/toybox/lightbox/

Its just not that well documented :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a Lightbox alternative that meets *all* of your requirements.

Personally, I am a big fan of [Shadowbox.](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) It meets your every requirement, except being free for commercial use.

Still, it is **nearly free**, priced at only $20 (single developer) or $50 (multiple developers) for unlimited use on any domain.